# Density described by Laplace equation

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations, diffusion

A Laplace's equation, say, describes the density $\rho(r,z)$ distribution in a 2D axisymmetric coordinate system:

$$\nabla^2 \rho=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial z^2}=0,\quad (r,z) \in \Omega$$

where $r$ and $z$ are the radial and axial coordinates, $\Omega$ is a spherical domain with a source of species in its center.

One then imposes a **zero** density gradient in the direction of the unit normal,
$\mathbf{n}=l^{-1}(r,z)$, of a bigger and bigger sphere surface $l=(r^2+z^2)^{1/2}$ **at infinity** with:

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{l \to +\infty}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \mathbf{n}}
=\lim_{l \to +\infty}\frac{r\rho_r+z\rho_z}{l}=0, \quad \mbox{with} \quad l=(r^2+z^2)^{1/2}.
\end{equation}

With a zero density gradient at infinity, we can say that the density is constant at infinity.

My question is:
In this case, could I further deduce that the density $\rho$ is **uniform everywhere** in the domain $\Omega$ including the border between $\Omega$ and the source? I came up with this guess according to the ''smoothing effect'' of Laplace's equation. Thanks for any comments.